# Getting undesirable output from fmsb::radarchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart, spider-chart

Here's my data. There are additional columns with data, but they are not included in the example.

| pain | fever | fatigue | headache |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23.4 | 17.2 | 45.6 | 32.9 |

```
library(fmsb)
radarchart(diary_aes_count2[,c(3:17)],
           maxmin = F,
           caxislabels = c(0, 15, 30, 45, 60),
           cglcol = "grey",
           vlcex = 60, cglty = 1, 
           cglwd = 0.5, axislabcol = "grey", 
           pcol = "black", plwd = 1, plty = 1)
```

My output is:

```
NA
 [DATA NOT ENOUGH] at 3
```

but multiple times over and a large black square.

Am I using the function incorrectly or is dataset constructed wrong?

Comment: You have only included 4 columns of data in the example but you seem to be using 15 in the code. And it's not clear how many rows you have etc. It's difficult to know whether there is a problem with your data from seeing only a small part of it. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include the output of `dput(diary_aes_count2)` so that we can test and verify possible solutions?